# What char variable really is?

Tags: java, variables, char

Both statements are valid:

```
char c1 = 'a';
char c2 = 97;
```

Now, if I add another char variable, lets say:

```
char c3 = 10;
```

And I sum c2 and c3 together like so:

```
int sum = c2 + c3
```

I do not get compile error and why is that?
And why would I need to ever sum two chars?

Thanks

Comment: Basically, there's an implicit conversion from `char` to `int` - and that gets used in *binary numeric promotion* as part of the addition operator.

Comment: *And why would I need to ever sum two chars?*  - Some form of checksum. maybe?  But it is moot.  A language designer should not forbid something just because he / she cannot think of a specific use-case for it.

Comment: Because all data is represented as _numbers_. Take a look at this [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). You might need to add characters together if you were writing anything that manipulates a `String` at a numeric level. Encryption. Hashing. Compression. Whatever else strikes your fancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each character represented by the type 'char' in java is mapped to a number in the ASCII table. When you add the values you are adding the operands numeric equivalent (the char types are cast as int) so x (120 ascii val) - P(80 ascii val) would give integer value 40.

```
Dec  Char                           Dec  Char     Dec  Char     Dec  Char
---------                           ---------     ---------     ----------
  0  NUL (null)                      32  SPACE     64  @         96  `
  1  SOH (start of heading)          33  !         65  A         97  a
  2  STX (start of text)             34  "         66  B         98  b
  3  ETX (end of text)               35  #         67  C         99  c
  4  EOT (end of transmission)       36  $         68  D        100  d
  5  ENQ (enquiry)                   37  %         69  E        101  e
  6  ACK (acknowledge)               38  &         70  F        102  f
  7  BEL (bell)                      39  '         71  G        103  g
  8  BS  (backspace)                 40  (         72  H        104  h
  9  TAB (horizontal tab)            41  )         73  I        105  i
 10  LF  (NL line feed, new line)    42  *         74  J        106  j
 11  VT  (vertical tab)              43  +         75  K        107  k
 12  FF  (NP form feed, new page)    44  ,         76  L        108  l
 13  CR  (carriage return)           45  -         77  M        109  m
 14  SO  (shift out)                 46  .         78  N        110  n
 15  SI  (shift in)                  47  /         79  O        111  o
 16  DLE (data link escape)          48  0         80  P        112  p
 17  DC1 (device control 1)          49  1         81  Q        113  q
 18  DC2 (device control 2)          50  2         82  R        114  r
 19  DC3 (device control 3)          51  3         83  S        115  s
 20  DC4 (device control 4)          52  4         84  T        116  t
 21  NAK (negative acknowledge)      53  5         85  U        117  u
 22  SYN (synchronous idle)          54  6         86  V        118  v
 23  ETB (end of trans. block)       55  7         87  W        119  w
 24  CAN (cancel)                    56  8         88  X        120  x
 25  EM  (end of medium)             57  9         89  Y        121  y
 26  SUB (substitute)                58  :         90  Z        122  z
 27  ESC (escape)                    59  ;         91  [        123  {
 28  FS  (file separator)            60  <         92  \        124  |
 29  GS  (group separator)           61  =         93  ]        125  }
 30  RS  (record separator)          62  >         94  ^        126  ~
 31  US  (unit separator)            63  ?         95  _        127  DEL
```

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html

This prints numbers 32-128 and the associated char:

```
for (int c=32; c<128; c++) 
{
     System.out.println("Ascii #: " + c + " Char" + ": " + (char)c);
}
```